# Sending images/attachments via Google Chat in Messages app

Tags: macos, messages, chat, jabber

Is it possible to send images or other attachments in the Messages desktop app (OS X) when talking to someone on Google Chat (Jabber)? I have tried sending files but they never receive them.

Comment: Old topic I know... but yeah, still annoying.  We used to use AOL Instant messenger around the office and that worked fantastically.  But ever since switching to GChat, we lost that capability.